# How to build a persistent hash?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have a node that subscribes to some messages and builds from that a data structure (which I would think of as a hash or dictionary). I would like the available keys not to be hardwired into the message definitions.

So calling this node the notekeeper, who subscribes to notes, I would want something like this:

note "name", "robot1"
note "mood", "happy"
note "emotion", 12

And then subsequently I would like other nodes using the notekeeper as a service (perhaps) asking

get_note "mood" and have it return "happy"

Do you follow? What's a good ROSish way of doing this?

#### Followup

My question comes from the fact that I am not sure of the process model that is involved and what kind of variable, object instance, global, survives while waiting for a subscription callback. If you store it in a dict as you recommend, where should that go, as an instance of a class created in the "main" program, in a "global" or where? Obviously it will not survive a crash of the node (or the robot).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282372/how-to-build-a-persistent-hash?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-11**:
Followup - I usually use a python class like in https://github.com/lucasw/simple_sim_ros/blob/master/sim_clock/scripts/clock.py , the dict would be created in the **init** and the subscribe and service callbacks would be class methods.  It's not more 'rosish' than any other approach but it works.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-11**:
If you want to save and reload the data the easiest way is probably putting it into a yaml file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can define your own key-pair message/s and a corresponding service with a key in the request and the value in the response.  The simplest thing would be to store initially non-string values into a string and have the msg and srv be each two strings, the 12 from your example would be a "12".

The node would subscribe to the StringString message type and be a String service provider, it could have a python dict or C++ `std::map<std::string, std::string>` for the data structure.

Or just use rosparams?

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-02-11**:
Thanks! See followup in original question?